# Restarting a Thread after returning to a Window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently building a point and click game in WPF, when I exit a room it changes windows at the moment, the problem is, when I return to a the Room I previously exited the movement thread won't resume.

My question is, after hiding a window and then using the .Show() on another window how do I restart the thread to ensure it runs?

Comment: Please post relevant code, it's unclear what happens to the thread when you exit a room

Comment: It's not clear at all how your GUI interacts with the "movement thread". Please post code and explain.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Thread.Pause() and Thread.Resume() when you show the window.